# Bypass MacOS 11.4 gatekeeper to test app with IPP 9.0 legacy code

Tags: macos-big-sur, intel-ipp

On my Mac Mini 2020 M1 development machine, I would like to test my app using IPP 2021.2.0 and 9.0 legacy code on Big Sur 11.4.

I have executed

> sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine path-to-testapp

but after starting from Rosetta terminal, I get

> libippac90lgc.dylib can not be opened, developer can not be verified

Is there some way to bypass this pain in the neck on  Big Sur 11.4?

Comment: It would be better if you let us know which application you are using. Or provide a small reproducer for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a **workaround** for the **gatekeeper verification problem** of **IPP 9.0 legacy dylibs**, I have just put them out of sight (i.e. **renamed all legacy dylibs** to .unused-dylib and hence the compiler links against the **static legacy libs**.